# Second Window os boot in Dell G7 laptop through external SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, multi-boot

I want to boot Second Window 10 OS installed in SSD into Dell G7 laptop through thunderbolt 3 port. Is it worth to that? Is it run smooth like internal hard disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a separate license - it cannot be your existing Windows 10 license. It should work - you might run into troubles with drive letters as Windows 10 will assume a constant drive letter.

I use VMware Workstation for additional machines as a virtualizer like this (or Hyper-V) is built for additional systems and runs them very well. I do this myself.

Comment: Thanks your answer. Yes, I have separate license for Win 10.  Issue is when I use VMware Workstation in current OS, then it share RAM for both OS, so I want to boot OS on startup. So I want to make sure it work without hang when I boot OS from SSD through thubderbolt port.

Comment: Just make sure when you make the machine that it keeps the same main drive letter.  I have not tried exactly that so I am not sure of all the details.